# Rails form validation failure for a form on a different models show view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form much like the one in the Rails getting started guide where a comments form is displayed on the show view of a different model. I'm having trouble with rendering the show view if model validation fails because when the show view re-renders I lose the ID of the other model with a "missing required keys: [:id]" error. It also redirects to the wrong url, topics/11/posts instead of just topics/11.

How can I get this to work?

My render path for an invalid form in the controller is

```
format.html { render template: "topics/show" }
```

and the form is

```
<%= form_for([topic, topic.comments.build]) do |f| %>
  <h2>Add new discussion topic</h2>
  <p>
    <%= f.text_field :title,  class: "form-control" %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.text_area :body, :rows => 6,  class: "form-control" %>
  </p>
  <p>
     <%= f.submit 'Submit', :class => 'btn' %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You're mentioning the "show" page, but when validation fails, its normal to re-render the "new" or "edit" page; is that what you mean?

Comment: Also, what do you mean when you say you lose the ID other "other model"; which one is the "other model"?

Comment: I just deleted my answer because I am not sure.  But I thought to try

    format.html { render template: "topics/show", :topic => #{topic_id} }

Comment: @PaulRichter The show page of the "other model" is where the comments form is displayed. There is no new or edit page. It's just like stack overflow, where the comment inputs are in the question "show" pages.

Comment: @trueinViso, I tried that and it doesn't work. I can't even find the documentation for the render function. Looks like it's deprecated in rails 4 (http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render). I tried using :locals => but that didn't do anything either.

Comment: @mer10z_tech Ah ok, gotcha. We may need some more information; where exactly is it failing (is it on the `form_for` line, for example)? Can you also post the full error message (the *missing required keys* part is usually only the last portion of a longer message).

Comment: Ok, so thanks for your comments, but I just re-wrote the form validation with Ajax so that I don't have to deal with the template rendering. It's a lot easier.

Comment: @mer10z_tech That was going to be one of my suggestions. That makes a lot more sense.